# How to load massive amount of data from Firebase Realtime Database

Tags: swift, flutter, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database

I have a pretty big problem.

I have two databases currently in my app. It's a meeting app. I am using MongoDB to store basic user data i.e. his name, surname, email and so on. And on Firebase Realtime Database I am storing the incomingRequests, sentRequests and friendsList.

So the question is following: How can I load massive amounts of data so that I can retrieve the userIds and statuses of the user from Firebase without doing it every time I open the app.

Currently, every time I open my app, I make a request to firebase to get me all of the user Ids that I have as friends. Then I query each userId and post a request to my MongoDB with the userId so that I can get user profile picture and username. I need to fix this because my loading times are 15+ seconds if someone has 100 friends for example.

So in summary, how can I solve this big data problem??

Comment: Try creating a cache of some kind. Save it locally somewhere, update the local store daily (or as needed). Have a `lastUpdated` variable in your objects and only retrieve items that have been updated since the last time you checked. If you download everything every time your data charges will likely be crazy high.

Comment: @loremipsum I have been trying to do that and It's so complex. I thought there might be another way but it looks like that is my only solution. Thank You.

Comment: You can use pagination. https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/query-cursors